# Facebook Like button does not register likes correctly

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, tumblr

I am maintaining a blog (in Tumblr): baierblog.com.
For the past few weeks the Facebook like buttons on the blog's posts are acting up.
Few of the posts' like buttons are OK, but others suffer from two problems:
**A.** Some buttons do not save the like count (you can click on the button but when you refresh the page, the button is reset and your like is not saved). for example: [sweet and sour chicken](http://baierblog.com/post/19733836593/sweet-and-sour-chicken).
**B.** Other buttons carry the like count of the blog itself (baierblog.com) and not of the exact post. for example: [corona brown bread](http://baierblog.com/post/20040868103/corona-brown-bread).

This behavior does not seem to be related to my code because when I enter the urls in the *Like buttons page* the generated buttons act the same.

The site passes the *Lint Debug*.

Any ideas?

**Update:** Though Mutant24 spotted an error, it does not seem to be the cause of the problem.
With out any interference by my part, the two examples given above now act the same. meaning, they both carry the like count of the blog itself (as do the Like buttons in the Like Button generation page for these urls).
The value held in graph.facebook.com/http://baierblog.com/post/19733836593/sweet-and-sour-chicken is the real like count of that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dori : in the og meta tags u have assigned wrong value in og:url

```
original url is - http://baierblog.com/post/17578099422/dark-chocolate-cake
and your are providing - http://baierblog.com/
```

Please fix it and check ur issues will be solved.

Comment: Thanks Charsee, this has been a big help

Comment: The main problem with fixing these sort of problems is that after you make a change in the meta tags, the Like button's behavior will be updated only after Facebook re-caches (or re-scans) you site (which can take a couple of days).

Comment: I indeed changed the og:url to the url of every post - that took care of the problem that my like counters were that of the entire blog.
This update took three days, but then, I got back to a state where my counters did not save the clicks.
I checked the Like buttons' generation page and saw I was getting an error regarding either my fb:admins or fb:app_id tags.
I corrected the fb:app_id tag (and the description tag, though I don't think it was relevant) and four days later the like buttons started acting normally.

Comment: I was not the one who created the Facebook application bounded to the blog (but because such an application existed I set the fb:app_id and not the fb:admins) and I wander what will happen to the like counters of the posts if I will delete the application from Facebook?

Comment: Dori: Though automatic re-caching of facebook is done in 2-3 days time but still if u want it be cached at the same time then trying using the fb lint debug tool. When you use this facebook re-caches your page at that moment and you can see the changes live on your new likes.

Comment: Charsee: Thanks for the tip, that really speeds the debugging process ;)

Answer (score 0):

Inserting the "Sweet and sour chicken"'s url into the [like button creator](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) produces the following error:

> The app ID specified within the "fb:app_id" meta tag is not allowed on
>   this domain. You must setup the Connect Base Domains for your app to
>   be a prefix of
>   http://baierblog.com/post/19733836593/sweet-and-sour-chicken.

Its attempting to like the post but failing.

Comment: I am aware of the error (and tried to fix it in a couple of methods, to no avail), but I don't believe it is the cause of the problem. As I mentioned, like buttons of other posts work fine. For example: [dark chocolate cake](http://baierblog.com/post/17578099422/dark-chocolate-cake).